# [Postgres Replication]Remote host is not reachable repmgr salve

Tags: postgresql, ssh, replication, pgbouncer, repmgr

I am trying to create a postgres replication configuration using two servers. The steps are similar to [PostgreSQL 9.4 Replication with RepMgr and PgBouncer on Ubuntu 14.04](http://blog.ashnab.com/postgresql-9-4-replication-with-repmgr-and-pgbouncer/)
 . I am using repmgr + pgbouncer as my replication configuration. Say I have two host dhost1 and dhost2. Repmgr meta data db is **repmgrdb** and user is **repmgr_user**. 
dhost1 has pgbouncer and Repmgr's configuration and it is the master. The  Repmgr's configuration in dbhost1 is mentioned below:

```
cluster = test

node = 1  
node_name = dhost1  
use_replication_slots = 1  
conninfo='host=dhost1 user=repmgr_user dbname=repmgrdb'  
pg_bindir=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin
## repmgr.conf at master ##
```

dhost2 also has Repmgr's config and it is in slave mode. It's config is mentioned below

```
cluster = test

node = 2  
node_name = dhost2  
use_replication_slots = 1  
conninfo='host=dhost2 user=repmgr_user dbname=repmgrdb'  
pg_bindir=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin
 ## repmgr.conf at slave ##
```

I am able to register to the master successfully and can be seen master in cluster show command.

on slave side I using `pg_basebackup` method to clone master with command

```
repmgr -f /etc/repmgr/repmgr.conf --force  -h dhost1_ip_address_goes_here> -U repmgr_user -d repmgrdb -v standby clone
```

For the above command I get the below error:

```
[2016-08-08 10:05:26] [NOTICE] using configuration file "/etc/repmgr/repmgr.conf"
[2016-08-08 10:05:26] [NOTICE] setting data directory to: /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main
[2016-08-08 10:05:26] [HINT] use -D/--data-dir to explicitly specify a data directory
[2016-08-08 10:05:26] [NOTICE] starting backup (using pg_basebackup)...
[2016-08-08 10:05:26] [HINT] this may take some time; consider using the -c/--fast-checkpoint option
[2016-08-08 10:05:31] [NOTICE] copying configuration files from master
[2016-08-08 10:05:31] [ERROR] aborting, remote host <dhost1_ip_address_goes_here> is not reachable.
[2016-08-08 10:05:31] [ERROR] unable to take a base backup of the master server>
[2016-08-08 10:05:31] [WARNING] destination directory (/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main) may need to be cleaned up manually
```

I also have set password-less ssh for `postgres` user between `dhost1` and `dhost2`.

Also I have been able to take `pg_basebackup` from command

```
pg_basebackup -h <dhost1_ip_address_goes_here> -P -v -U repmgr_user -X stream -D 9.5/main -R
```

I am very beginner for postgresql replication please suggest me answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking into that right now. You might wanna run the command again with
  --log-level DEBUG --verbose
That should give some more info on what is going on there...

Answer (score -1):

1-st

rm -rf /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/*

2-nd

repmgr -h masterhostname  -p 5433 -U repmgr -d repmgr -D main -f /etc/repmgr.conf --copy-external-config-files=pgdata --verbose standby clone

3-rd

pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main --log=/var/log/postgresql/postgres_screen.log  start
4-th

repmgr -f /etc/repmgr/repmgr.conf standby register;

repmgr -f /etc/repmgr/repmgr.conf cluster show

Comment: Please add an explanation.